# how to update/edit exsiting post/transaction?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to update a transaction with a put request but there seems to a mismatch between my controller and actions. it's throwing a 404 error, what is the disconnect between controller.js and actions.js ?

**edit: it is now throwing another error after i made changes**

*Transaction validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., amount: Path `amount` is required., category: Path `category` is required."*

controller.js

```
const updateTransaction = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, amount, currency, category } = req.body;
  const transaction = await Transaction.findById(req.params.id);
  if (transaction) {
    transaction.name = name;
    transaction.amount = amount;

    transaction.category = category;
    const updatedTransaction = await transaction.save();
    res.json(updatedTransaction);
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("Transaction not found");
  }
});
```

actions.js

```
export const updateTransaction = (transaction) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: TRANSACTION_UPDATE_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.put(
      `/api/transactions/${transaction._id}`,
      transaction
    );

    dispatch({
      type: TRANSACTION_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
    dispatch({ type: TRANSACTION_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: TRANSACTION_UPDATE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

edit transaction modal

```
  const onSubmit = (_id) => {
    dispatch(updateTransaction({ _id: transactionId }));
  };
```

request as a fetch

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/transactions/6111ea25c354c73b10a50530", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"92\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"92\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?1",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
  },
  "referrer": "http://localhost:3000/transactions/edit/6111ea25c354c73b10a50530/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "{\"_id\":\"6111ea25c354c73b10a50530\",\"values\":{\"category\":\"expense\",\"name\":\"terrwer\",\"amount\":\"2\"}}",
  "method": "PUT",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

server.js

```
app.use("/api/transactions", transactionRoutes);
```

transactionModel.js

```
const transactionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
 
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    amount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },

  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Transaction = mongoose.model("Transaction", transactionSchema);

export default Transaction;
```

Comment: In the devtools you can copy the request made (network tab) as [fetch or curl](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/167-copy-as-fetch/) and see what is actually sent, could you add that to the question?

Comment: it says: Error: Not Found - /api/transactions/6111ea25c354c73b10a50531<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at errorHandler. which is strange since it is the transaction I am working on? –

Comment: What data is sent? I mentioned copy the request as fetch or curl so you can see what is actually sent. The thunk is using url `/api/transactions` but the controller you posted is `transaction`

Comment: just updated the post. is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Looks like `req.params.id` could not be set depending on the express route (missing) or maybe the schema does not have [id set up correctly](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/find-by-id) but that is missing as well. You could have left out the react code as the request seems to have been made correctly, just focus on express and mongoose and relevant code.

Comment: i chose to have the schema automatically apply an id. could you check if the model schema is valid? i have updated the post

Comment: You are using `req.params.id` but dont see any code with a path `/api/transactions/:id` I assume it's in your code because you are not getting a 404. Mongoose should have added the [id to schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) so that should be fine. The error you are getting is that you are missing `name`, `path` and `amount` but the request in your question has those, are you sure the request posted is the failed one?

Comment: You could try `const { values: {name, amount, currency, category }} = req.body;` since these values are in `request.body.values` and not in `request.body` did you look at the request details you added in your question?

Comment: is there an article or resource that shows how to read fetch data that you send a link to? i wasnt aware that was a method to debug in the first place

Comment: HMR that was the correct answer.